# Check for open text file

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a Python application with opens several text files in different threads. I want each thread to make some operations on the file while it is open. When the external text editor closes the file the processing of the corresponding thread should stop. So I need to check on whether the text file is still opened or not.

```
class MyThread (Thread):

def __init__(self, sf):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.sf = sf # sourcefile

def run (self):
    subprocess.Popen([EDITOR, self.sf])
```

The problem now is that subprocess opens the file in the editor and run() terminates. How can I keep the run() open until I close the file externally?

Comment: If your Python code is reading and/or writing the file, why do you need to have an external editor open at the same time?

Comment: The python code doesn't do anything with the content of the text files. The idea is using the capabilities of the text editor (vi). The processing taking place is actually transforming the contents to html and saving it into another file.

Comment: The text Editor probably only opens the file for a short time while reading and writing.  It might or might not lock the file, create a "swap" file etc, during that time.  A better approach is to look for when the file changes, either by poling modification time, or else using something like `inotify`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the subprocess.call method?

```
subprocess.call('notepad')
```

This waits for the command to complete before the process terminates and returns control back to the program.

This is what i wrote:

import subprocess
    from threading import Thread

```
class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, sf):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sf = sf

    def run(self):

        subprocess.call('notepad ' + self.sf)


def main():
    myThread = MyThread('test.txt')
    myThread.start()
    while myThread.isAlive():
        print "Still Alive"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program keeps printing "Still Alive" till I close the notepad window.

Comment: Yes, I tried that before but didn't work. After starting every thread I append them to a list. After that I loop over the list with thread.isAlive() and I can see that it still stops immediately.

Comment: Strange. This is what I wrote import subprocess
from threading import Thread


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, sf):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sf = sf

    def run(self):

        subprocess.call('notepad ' + self.sf)


def main():
    myThread = MyThread('test.txt')
    myThread.start()
    while myThread.isAlive():
        print "Still Alive"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() . It keeps printing "Still Alive" till I close the notepad window.

Comment: I tried your code and it prints out "Still Alive" while the text editor is starting up, when the file is fully loaded it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You have two events: FileOpen and FileClose. FileOpen happens when the editor is opened. FileClose is done when the editor closes? Or when the editor closes the file? If it's just on closing the editor then it should be straightforward to find out when the subprocess closes and then kill the worker threads.

Unless an editor provides a particular API, it's going to be a really nasty hack to find out if it closed the file but the editor remains open. E.g. You may have to poll lsof and process the output.

It sounds similar to what a revision control system does when you commit a file and it opens an editor for you. Maybe you should check the hg or bzr code bases. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ehiggs/388139) is how mercurial handles it. And [here](https://gist.github.com/ehiggs/388161) is how bazaar handles it.

I changed Shekar's version to work with vim and use the list as a command in the subprocess.call command (and added imports) . It works as he describes.

```
from threading import Thread                                                    
import subprocess                                                               
class MyThread(Thread):                                                         
    def __init__(self, sf):                                                     
        Thread.__init__(self)                                                   
        self.sf = sf                                                            
    def run(self):                                                              
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/vim', self.sf])                              

def main():                                                                     
    myThread = MyThread('test.txt')                                             
    myThread.start()                                                            
    while myThread.isAlive():                                                   
        print "Still Alive"                                                     

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was calling the editor MacVim via command line with /usr/bin/mvim. Now I changed it to /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim and it works as expected. I think that is because it checks the only process which it handles directly, in the first case it was the terminal and not the editor.